# I want to draw text on second screen without form

Tags: c#

I want to draw text on second screen without form using c#

i'm using this code:

```
var hdc = CreateDC(@"\\.\DISPLAY2", "","", IntPtr.Zero);

Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(hdc);
```

but when I run this code and try draw on second screen, text shown but text background is first screen background (primary)

[image: Picture for my problem]

I want to draw text on second screen without form using c#

Comment: `CreateDC(@"\\.\DISPLAY", "DISPLAY2", null, IntPtr.Zero)` maybe? Did you first call `EnumDisplayDevices` like the docs say? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdcw

Comment: now ,i call EnumDisplayDevices but still  background of first screen show in second screen

Comment: I would create a transparent form without borders and draw on it.

Comment: I think that before writing the text you should paint a rectangle to "clean" the backgound. If not cleaned, the backgound might contain any rest of image from other drawing operations.